# Footer comes above, when I set the float value to right

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

I am new here and with CSS. I am trying to place my footer under the content section. Whenever content gets bigger, the footer will set its position depening on the content. But I could not do it. 
This is the picture of the web site. I want it to be two sided web site, right for the content and left for the tweets. As you see how footer comes above.

Actually Footer comes above, when I set the float value to right for Aside. When it is none, Footer works as I want it.

These are the codes:

Content Comes Here 
 Tweets come here

These are the CSS code:

```
section {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 55%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}


aside {
    margin-right: 5%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: right;
}


footer {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ca171b;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-style: groove;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-bottom-width: 8px;
    border-left-style: ridge;
    border-left-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-right-style: ridge;
    border-right-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css give your footer clear:both

Also if you want your section and aside blocks to be side by side, you can float them both left and their combined width (including margins) should be 100%..or less

https://jsfiddle.net/sgey3698/1/

```
section {
float: left;
width: 55%;
margin-right: 5%;
background: white;
padding-top: 10px;
}


aside {
width: 40%;
padding-top: 10px;
float: left;
}


footer {
height: 30px;
background-color: #ca171b;
border-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-style: groove;
border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
border-bottom-width: 8px;
border-left-style: ridge;
border-left-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
border-left-width: 3px;
border-right-width: 3px;
border-right-style: ridge;
border-right-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
font-size: 1.2em;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 5%;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
z-index: 1;
clear: both;
}
```